# How to assert that a class will respond_to a class method with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec2

Let's say I have a class definition like so:

```
class Foo
  def init(val)
    @val = val
  end

  def self.bar
    :bar
  end

  def val
    @val
  end
end
```

with a spec like:

```
describe Foo
  it { should respond_to(:val) }
  it { should respond_to(:bar) }
end
```

The second `it` assertion fails. It isn't clear to me from RSpec's documentation that `respond_to` should fail on class methods.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your example should be written like this:

```
it 'should respond to ::bar' do
  Foo.should respond_to(:bar)
end
```

Answer (score 18):

Nowadays it is suggested we use expect, like this:

```
describe Foo do
  it 'should respond to :bar' do
    expect(Foo).to respond_to(:bar)
  end
end
```

See: http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

Actually you can make this approach by providing a subject:

```
describe Foo do
  subject { Foo }
  it { should respond_to :bar } # :bar being a class method
end
```

As described in here: http://betterspecs.org/#subject